# Apache is not recognizing the alias on my websites

Tags: apache, tomcat

If you could help me with this query. I am working on an Ubuntu server with Apache2, I have two Laravel websites that I use for my backend. The problem I have is that it does not recognize the alias of the second website and it gives me the 404 NOT FOUND error when trying to enter the website. When entering with the IP url that I use http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx without problem it enters /var/www/html but when using http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/meditime/ that is where I get this problem 404 NOT FOUND, my Apache configuration is as follows.

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName xxx.xx.xx.xxx

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/html_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/html_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

y este meditime.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
            Alias /meditime /var/www/meditime

    DocumentRoot /var/www/meditime
    <Directory /var/www/meditime>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/meditime_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/meditime_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The routes are fine, both websites have been tested and they open without problem. The problem is that it is not assuming the alias. Furthermore, they are all already enabled.